# ASP.NET WEB SERVICE: Adding custom attribute C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

Hi can I add an attribute to my asp.net web service header?

I need to include something like: xmlns:trac="http://whatever".

This is my code:

```
namespace com.chronopost.notification.push.trace.webservice
{ 
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://webservice.trace.push.notification.chronopost.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class TracePushWSService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string TraceMessageFeedback(DtTrackTraceParamUserCredential mtTrackTraceParamUserCredential, string mtTrackTraceTestFeedBack)
        {

            return "DTM00: TracePush Feedback:  " + mtTrackTraceTestFeedBack;

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public DtTrackTraceAnswer NewTraceMessage(DtTrackTraceParamUserCredential mtTrackTraceParamUserCredential, DtTrackTraceParam mtTrackTraceReq)
        {

            DtTrackTraceAnswer iDtTrackTraceResp = new DtTrackTraceAnswer("DTM00: TracePush OBJ - OK");

            return iDtTrackTraceResp;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public DtTrackTraceAnswerXML NewTraceMessageXML(DtTrackTraceParamUserCredential mtTrackTraceParamUserCredential, DtTrackTraceParamXML mtTrackTraceReqXML)
        {

            DtTrackTraceAnswerXML iDtTrackTraceResp = new DtTrackTraceAnswerXML("DTM00: TracePush XML - OK");

            return iDtTrackTraceResp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you want. Just go to your class objetcs and set the XmlRoot. Prefix and namespace: trac = http://whatever.
It will become available in the soap envelope.

Answer (score 0):

If I understoo you correctly you need [SoapExtension Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx), you can look the example in the msdn, about creating Attribute for the Web Service Method.

> ASP.NET allows a SOAP-related infrastructure to be built by means of
>   an extensibility mechanism. The ASP.NET SOAP extension architecture
>   revolves around an extension that can inspect or modify a message at
>   specific stages in message processing on either the client or the
>   server. ASP.NET SOAP extensions derive from the SoapExtension class.
>   The GetInitializer and Initialize methods provide alternative
>   mechanisms for initializing the SOAP extension to enhance performance.
>   ProcessMessage is the heart of most SOAP extensions, as the method is
>   called at each stage defined in SoapMessageStage, allowing the SOAP
>   extension to perform the desired behavior of that specific SOAP
>   extension. For SOAP extensions that need to modify the SOAP request or
>   SOAP response, ChainStream provides an opportunity to receive the
>   proposed data to be sent across the wire.